# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on observing table view contentSize value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ran into an interesting error today and wondering how I can address it or make this code more robust so that my app doesn't crash. 99% of the time this code works fine and does exactly what I want it to do, but 1% of the time it crashes and Xcode just shows an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

[image]

Off the top of my head, I am thinking that the app is crashing because I am observing a property that really isn't made to be observed. Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: KVO is not run on main thread, and you modify the `preferredContentSize` there. Add `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` around that assignment statement.

Comment: @zaitsman You're a wizard. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, KVO typically does not run on main thread.

So most likely, when your value observation call back is called in Swift, you need to dispatch your assignment to main thread as you're changing a UI property of the View Controller.

Wrap your statement in a dispatch to main thread like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // your code here
}
```